# タイムゾーンを指定した上で今日の日付 Date.today を知りたい

Tags: ruby

ローカルのタイムゾーンではなく UTC での [`Date.today`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Date.html#S_TODAY) が知りたいのですが、Date クラスのみからの操作で知ることはできますか？　Time クラスを使えば `Time.now.utc.to_date` と取得できることは分かったのですが、Date クラスを使って取得することはできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この回答を読んで解決しました：https://stackoverflow.com/a/10219875/5989200

Date はタイムゾーンを変えることを意識しておらず、常にローカル時刻を参照します。タイムゾーンを指定したい場合は Time を使います：`Time.now.utc.to_date`。

もう少し詳しく見てみましょう。`Date.today` の[実装](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/8474e6ae1f327acb3e137c191078a522682cc946/ext/date/date_core.c#L3673)は次のようになっています。

```c
time_t t;
struct tm tm;
// ...
if (time(&t) == -1)
  rb_sys_fail("time");
tzset();
if (!localtime_r(&t, &tm))
  rb_sys_fail("localtime");
```

このあと `tm` が Date を作るのに使われます。上のコードのように `localtime()` が `tm` を作るのに使われているため、Date が返すのはローカル時間になります。